# When I print out in terminal there is always a "%" behind my output. How to fix it?

Tags: java, system.out

I'm trying to practice some data structure using Java. And when I print out in terminal there is always a "%" behind my output. Does anyone know how to fix it?
This is the output of the terminal

```
(base) ➜  desktop javac ReverseLinkedList1.java
(base) ➜  desktop java ReverseLinkedList1      
1->2->3->4->5
5->4->3->2->1%
```

I want to know why there is a "%".

This is my code, it is about the reversing a linked list.

```java
public class ReverseLinkedList1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ListNode head = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode node1 = new ListNode(2);
        ListNode node2 = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode node3 = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode tail = new ListNode(5);
        head.next = node1;
        node1.next = node2;
        node2.next = node3;
        node3.next = tail;
        ListNode head2 = head;
        //print out the initial list
        while (head2 != null){
            System.out.print(head2.val);
            head2 = head2.next;
            if(head2 != null){
                System.out.print("->");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        head2 = reverseLinkedList(head);
        //peinr out the reversed list
        while (head2 != null){
            System.out.print(head2.val);
            //System.out.print("^");
            head2 = head2.next;
            if(head2 != null){
                System.out.print("->");
            }
        }
    }

    public static ListNode reverseLinkedList(ListNode head){
        if (head == null) {
            return head;
        }
        //1   ->    2   ->   3
        //prev -> current - > next

        ListNode prev = head;
        ListNode current = head.next;
        prev.next = null;
        while(current != null){
            ListNode next = current.next;
            // current -> prev
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        //prev is the head of the reversed linked list
        return prev;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `%` seems to be the prompt of your terminal/shell, and is not output of your program. Add a `System.out.println()` at the end of your main method so it ends up on a new line.

Comment: Yeah, the % disappeared after adding a System.out.println(). Thanks a lot!